# PL/SQL - read external table

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, external-tables

I have dynamically created a table and wrote a data from .csv file. I have done it  inside a procedure passing created table name as a parameter. Now, I would like to read a data from this table or ideally, I would like to write a whole data from this table to cursor or array inside the same procedure as I need to compare them from data stored inside DB. I have tried to create dynamic cursors and array but didn't work. Is there any method to achieve that?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE My_procedure (p_ext_table_name   VARCHAR2,
                                                    p_file_name        VARCHAR2)
    AS
        v_ext_create   VARCHAR2 (10000);
        v_ext_table_name varchar2(100);
        --emp_refcur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
        --type ext_tab is table of EXT_table%rowtype;
        --emp_tab ext_tab;
    BEGIN
     
     v_ext_table_name := p_ext_table_name;
     v_ext_create :=
     'CREATE TABLE ' || p_ext_table_name || q'! ( 
      CUSTOMER_ID                      NUMBER,
      CUSTOMER_MAILING  CHAR(2 BYTE))
      ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
      (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
         DEFAULT DIRECTORY  MY_DIRECTORY
            ACCESS PARAMETERS 
           ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
        ( Customer_ID,
          New_Customer_Mailing ))
        LOCATION (MY_DIRECTORY:'!' || p_file_name || q'!')
      )
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
    PARALLEL ( DEGREE 5 INSTANCES 1 )!';
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_ext_create;
    
    
    
    END;
```

My ideas:

```
    /*open emp_refcur 'select CUSTOMER_ID from' || v_ext_table_name|| USING CUSTOMER_ID;
    LOOP
        FETCH EMP_REFCUR INTO CUSTOMER_ID;
        EXIT WHEN EMP_REFCUR%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CUSTOMER_ID);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE EMP_REFCUR;*/ didn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually bad practice to dynamically create tables in PL/SQL. It creates all sorts of problems: SQL is a strongly typed language and - as you're discovering - it's hard to write code which will compile and run against objects which only exist at runtime.

You haven't explained your total business requirement but it doesn't seem like you need to dynamically create the table. Probably you just need to change the file your table points at. If that is the case:

1. Create the table **once**.
2. When you need to load some table change the file. Here is a procedure which can do that:

```
create or replace procedure change_ext_table_file (p_file_name in varchar2) ) is
begin
  execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE your_ext_table LOCATION (''' || p_file_name || ''')';
end;
```

3. Now you can query your_ext_table and join it to other tables using static SQL.